# NUMTODSINTERVAL in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, oracle, postgresql

Is there a function in ***PostgreSQL*** that is the same as `NUMTODSINTERVAL(n, interval unit)` in *Oracle*?

Comment: For those of us not in the know, what does `NUMTODSINTERVAL` *do*? What problem are you trying to solve  by using it? For the input, what output do you expect? (If I asked you "Is there an Oracle equivalent of `to_tsvector`", what would you say?)

Comment: i want to get interval like INTERVAL '1 day' bu in my case number is variable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want a functionality similar to [this](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/functions093.htm) function (i.e. the unit is variable -- not constant): a simple concatenation & a cast is enough in PostgreSQL:

```
select cast(num || unit as interval)
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d41d8/2704)

You can read more about `interval`'s input formats [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-INTERVAL-INPUT).

Comment: Thank you! I ended up with a SQL function for this:
`emanuel=# CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION numtoyminterval(num integer, unit varchar) RETURNS interval IMMUTABLE LANGUAGE sql AS $$ SELECT cast(num || unit as interval) $$ ;
select numtoyminterval(2,'day');
-- 2 days`

It is more performant the `interval '1' day * n`, however it is easier to change units using the cast.

Answer (score 6):

Just multiply your variable with the desired interval:

```
interval '1' day * n
```

Since Postgres 9.4 you can also use the function [make_interval()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/functions-datetime.html)

```
make_interval(days => n)
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. A multiplication is cheaper an less error prone than concatenation + cast. Equivalent syntax: `interval '1 day' * n`

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter that's true, but what if the unit is a variable/column value? That can't be expressed this way. But of course, if the unit is constant, multiplication is a better solution.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter: note that `interval '1' day` is the syntax specified in the SQL standard for intervals. `interval '1 day'` is a Postgres extension to that.

Comment: @pozs: It works with all values coming from columns. The unit would be the *value* `interval '1' day` etc.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter yeah, but that's not the case (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24996162/numtodsinterval-in-postgresql#comment38863057_24996162) -- so effectively that solution would require a concatenation and a multiplication -- or redesign the schema, but that case the two column can be merged into a single interval.

Comment: @pozs: Concatenation would be equally efficient if time units were provided as `text`. But the OP states: `number is variable`. So this answer is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

`'1 day'::interval` 
do something like this.